# NoClassDefFoundError but classes exist

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, bukkit

I am developing two Bukkit plugins using 1.7.9-R0.2 version API.

I am not using Maven. I export them as *Java > JAR file*.
They are similar and they are installed on the same server.

`NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown, but classes exist!

Comment: Check you manifest file for correct imports ... No class def found occurs if the manifest in missing the import. Just by having dependencies in build path get around the compile errors and not runtime ones.

Comment: When you unzip you jar you should see an META-INF folder. There should be a manifest in that ! Check that it would be missing the packages in the import section for all the class def not found.

Comment: @StackFlowed It contains: `Manifest-Version: 1.0`.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError *does not* mean that the .class file doesn't exist.  What it means is that a .class file that purported to be the class *was* found, but for some reason the (presumed) class representation contained therein could not be "prepared" for use.  Most often this is because of a JAR version mismatch, but it can be for about a dozen other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Bukkit **bug**, found [here](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/nosuchmethodexception-if-i-have-2-plugins-with-the-same-class-name.130623/).

Do not create multiple classes with the same path into two different plugins.
You can use a top package called with the plugin name.